# I got some flexbox , ul and li issues

Tags: html, css

I have a flexbox navbar using ul with a height of 86px. I centered
the li-s using align-items: center, but when I want to add a
background-color hover effect on the list items, having the same
the height as the ul, the list items just jump to the top of the ul and
it's no more centered...Why's that? I applied display flex on the
li-s using `align-items` center and this way was okay, but I know this isn't the right way to do it, because you need to apply flex on
parent elements...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 86px;
  background-color: beige;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

ul li {
  height: 86px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Products</li>
    <li>FAQ</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: i don't think i understand your problem. can't you just remove the `height: 86px;` on the `li`-elements if you want them centered? how does this conflict with a hover effect? it would be helpful if you could reproduce your problem

Comment: so basically you want li should take full height and it should be hoverable ?

Comment: Yes, exactly...i want a background-color for the li-s on hover with 86px, as it parent element

Answer (score 1):

Just remove height from both the element if you want `li` to take full width of the navbar and adjust its width as per the padding. This is the normal and I guess a good approach to do this.
Your code was just adding `height` hence text inside it went up. Remove it and add some `padding` to `li`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: beige;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

ul li {
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Products</li>
    <li>FAQ</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, I think you need to remove the height set for both the ul and li elements and add appropriate padding to the ul element, so this would be the entire css:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: beige;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 15px;
    padding: 43px 0;
}
```

I ran this locally and got a vertically and horizontally centered chunk of li items.

Answer (score 0):

You Set `height:86px` to your `li` elements and that is causing the problem

you can increase their height using padding-top and padding-bottom or not to add any height to `li` elements and just let the `align-items` to work

IF

li heights is a must you can set `line-height` to them as well

```
li{
    height:86px;
    line-height: 86px;
}
```

here in this fiddle I've just removed `li` heights and it's working

Answer (score 0):

When aligning `li` flex items on the y-axis I would use `display: flex;` on both the `ul` and `li`. Then just simply add `height: 100%;` to your `li`'s for the `background-color` to cover the full height and you are good to go.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 86px;
  background-color: beige;
}

ul,
li {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

li {
  height: 100%;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}

li:nth-child(2):hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Products</li>
    <li>FAQ</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```